# Pass in Table name to Javascript Document Get Element ID function

Tags: javascript, html

I want to be able to make buttons to hide or show tables on my web page, rather than making a new function for each table Id like to just make one, that takes an argument name which will be the div ID of the table. 
The function works whwn I dont pass in an argument and hard code the solution but when I try passing in a string thats when it stops working.

I have tried creating a PHP variable and passing that, but all of it breaks the code. It seems like the function is not being called at all, because when I included an alert function it wasn't called.

Working Code

```
echo "<button onclick='myFunction()'>View La Liga</button>
    <div id='myDIV' style='display:none'>";

....

<script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
 }
}
</script>
```

Broken code

```
echo "<button onclick='myFunction('myDIV')'>View La Liga</button>
    <div id='myDIV' style='display:none'>";

....

<script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction(y) {
    var x = document.getElementById(y);
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
 }
}
</script>
```

This should allow me to just call the function with the div name rather than hard code it, but the function does not get called at all. I feel like I am making a simple mistake.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38739465/need-third-kind-of-quotation-marks-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should escape the quotes, something like this:

```
echo '<button onclick="myFunction(\'myDIV\')">View La Liga</button>
    <div id="myDIV" style="display:none">';
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought I had tried this but I did ' ".myDIV. " '

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same type of quotation mark twice because of the `string` in here:

```
'myFunction('myDIV')'
```

Change your code, replacing `'` to `"` in the argument.
Like this:

```
<button onclick='myFunction(\'myDIV\')'>View La Liga</button>
    <div id='myDIV' style='display:none'>
```

Comment: What about quotes for PHP's `echo`?

Comment: Yes, I forgot about it for a second. Edited. Consider the other answer.

Comment: What about if I wanted to pass in a php variable rather than a string, would that look the same. (\$variable['column']\)

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the quotes around the id in the PHP echo call

```
echo "<button onclick='myFunction(\'myDIV\')'>View La Liga</button>
<div id='myDIV' style='display:none'>";
```